# Skrollr fails to move more than 20 objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, skrollr

I'm developing with skrollr a page with several words that come in when you scroll the page down ending with a word cloud. The functions used are opacity, transform:rotate, transform translateX, translateY. Skrollr version is 0.6.30.
It's working pretty good untile I reached the 20 word and the other following this twentieth. These latest words move but often these stop in the middle of the expected path. This mostly happens when you scroll at high speed.
Above you can see the code where Word20 and Word21 are not working properly.

```css
.word5{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align:center;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.word4{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align:center;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.word3{
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<p class="word5"
  data-100="opacity:0; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(700px) translateY(200px)"
  data-500="opacity:1; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(125px) translateY(-40px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(125px) translateY(-40px)">
  WORD1</p>
   <p class="word5"
  data-100="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(500px) translateY(500px)"
  data-500="opacity:1; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(175px) translateY(130px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(175px) translateY(130px)">
  WORD2</p>
   <p class="word5"
  data-100="opacity:0; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(20px) translateY(700px)"
  data-500="opacity:1; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(20px) translateY(345px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(20px) translateY(345px)">
  WORD3</p>
   <p class="word5"
  data-100="opacity:0; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(800px)"
  data-500="opacity:1; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(190px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(0px) translateY(190px)">
  WORD4</p>
   <p class="word5"
  data-100="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-600px) translateY(400px)"
  data-500="opacity:1; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-55px) translateY(60px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-55px) translateY(60px)">
  WORD5</p>
   <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(900px) translateY(500px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(490px) translateY(-30px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(490px) translateY(-30px)">
  WORD6</p>
    <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(900px) translateY(-580px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(10px) translateY(-580px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(10px) translateY(-580px)">
  WORD7</p>
 <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(900px) translateY(-300px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(95px) translateY(-300px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(95px) translateY(-300px)">
  WORD8</p>
 <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(900px) translateY(500px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(290px) translateY(60px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(290px) translateY(60px)">
  WORD9</p>
 <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-800px) translateY(-300px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(50px) translateY(-20px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(50px) translateY(-20px)">
  WORD10</p>
 <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-600px) translateY(180px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-50px) translateY(180px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-50px) translateY(180px)">
  WORD11</p>
 <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-600px) translateY(-200px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-110px) translateY(-125px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-110px) translateY(-125px)">
  WORD12</p>
 <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-800px) translateY(-300px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-215px) translateY(-125px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-215px) translateY(-125px)">
  WORD13</p>
 <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-800px) translateY(-100px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-110px) translateY(140px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-110px) translateY(140px)">
  WORD14</p>
    <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(900px) translateY(200px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(490px) translateY(75px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(490px) translateY(75px)">
  WORD15</p>
 <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-800px) translateY(100px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-185px) translateY(-30px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-185px) translateY(-30px)">
  WORD16</p>
 <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-800px) translateY(800px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-145px) translateY(445px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-145px) translateY(445px)">
  WORD17</p>
  <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(900px) translateY(200px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(335px) translateY(105px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(335px) translateY(105px)">
  WORD18</p>
 <p class="word4"
  data-300="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(400px) translateY(600px)"
  data-600="opacity:1; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(335px) translateY(85px)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(335px) translateY(85px)">
  WORD19</p>
    <p class="word4"
  data-400="opacity:0; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(900px) translateY(-580px)"
  data-700="opacity:1; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(155px) translateY(-455x)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(90deg) translateX(155px) translateY(-455px)">
  WORD20</p>
 <p class="word3"
  data-400="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(-900px) translateY(-580px)"
  data-700="opacity:1; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0x)"
  data-2000="opacity:0; transform:rotate(0deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px)">
  WORD21</p>
 </body>
   <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/skrollr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       skrollr.init({
   smoothScrolling: false,
   mobileDeceleration: 0.004
    });
   </script>
</html>
```

Does anyone know if this is a kind of limitation of skroll or javascript? OR someone know a way to reach the same kind of output?
Thank you very much.

Comment: I've found that the words after the 25th are working properly again. It looks very weird...

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. I wrote "x" instead of "px" and with some copy&paste I've replicated the errors making the browser unable to easy interpretate the movement coordinates. A very silly mistake.